# Recycle View had the half of the height

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, recyclerview-layout

I have a problem with this Recycle View on this layout, it don't take the complete height of your father container.

I used the weight parameters, but that is not the problem i think.

Check the code and Print screen.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/subjects"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_subject_tab" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/usageStatusListContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="@color/colorLight">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/chapters"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:divider="@color/colorLight"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_chapter_usage_status"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ6CY.png)

Comment: post your `item_subject_tab` layout code

Comment: Is there any reason for using a ConstraintLayout?  If not then try simply using the LinearLayout as root layout (or exchange the ConstraintLayout for a FrameLayout)

Comment: I rechecked very well the item , and founded the problem on it, A relative layout in a item without match_parent of height. Thanks !!!  Im, new on stackoverflow as User, let me know how can vote your reply.

Comment: You're welcome :) and thanks for the offer, but I think you know better than I what actually solved your problem (I certainly did not mention any RelativeLayouts in my comment). So if you like you can answer your own question (and accept it after a while) Happy coding!